# GKEでNodePortとIngressを使ってアプリケーションを公開する場合の料金は？

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

GKEでコンテナをtype=NodePortで立ち上げ、それをHTTPS経由で提供したいので、Ingressを利用してサービスへ疎通させました。これでアプリケーションはSSL対応できたわけですが、問題は料金についてです。

GCPではロードバランサに対してお金がかかると聞きました。

参考: https://tech.libinc.co.jp/entry/2019/03/22/105911

今回はNodePortとIngressを使ったのでロードバランサは使っていません。

- Ingress
- NodePort
- LoadBalancer <- 使ってない

でもIngressが実はロードバランサみたいな扱いだったらと危惧しています。

(理想はIngressとNodePortのセットを10個とか作ってもお金がかからない状態というものですが、もしかしてIngressを10個立ち上げるとロードバランサが10個立ち上がるのと同じことなになるのか？)

なるべく安く公開する方法を探していて、上記では安くならない、もっと安くする方法があるといった場合、それについても教えていただけると嬉しいです。